# localization and local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a small question, which I could not verify with
a quick search on the internet. Is it true that if I have a
commutative ring $A$, and some multiplicative set $S$,
then the localized ring $S^{-1}A$ is always a local ring?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not the case if $S = \{1\}$, for example, since $S^{-1}A \approx A$ in that case. However, $S^{-1}A$ will always be local if $S = A - \mathfrak{p}$ for some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$.